# Site available in local network after host url changed

Tags: angular, angular-universal

In my angular app I had to change host url to make connection with API and some other server. So locally my site is running on https://foo.com:4000 . I want to test my site on other devices and make this site available in my local network. Usually I was using for that: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` but this time I can't use ng serve for that because my site is rendering on server.

How can I simply make my site available in my local network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work all you have to do is run the API and the Angular server in different ports, just make sure that it's the case.

Edit: if you are hosting your web API with the angular files inside then you have to tell us your Web API technology so that as nothing to do with Angular

Edit 2 : You have to connect to your IP address not the DNS that you defined on your machine

Comment: My API server is hosted online so it's not a problem. The problem is that my site is running on my Mac correctly on https://foo.com:4000 but I can't get this site on same address on my second computer (windows) which's on same network.

Comment: Are you accessing the correct IP address of you machine that is hosting the server? Try pinging via cmd your address in that second machine

Comment: Yes, my mac address is 192.168.0.11, app is running on foo.com:4000. On windows I can ping 192.168.0.11, but can't ping/access foo.com:4000

Comment: I have done a test to this example you present to me and it works fine, only thing happens it's the requests made  to the API are blocked due to cors origin but that has nothing to do about the angular interface ( those can be seen in the developer tools console)

Comment: I was accesing wrong IP, everything works fine when I access https://192.168.0.11:4000